# ADO YAML pipeline - Passing object parameter to a template

Tags: loops, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've got a yaml pipeline calling a template:

```
parameters:
  - name: Food1
    type: string
  - name: Food2
    type: string
  - name: Food3
    type: string

jobs:
  - template: .\testLoop.yml
    parameters: 
      foodObject: |
        Food1: ${{ parameters.Food1 }}
        Food2: ${{ parameters.Food2 }}
        Food3: ${{ parameters.Food3 }}
```

The template's input parameter is of "object" type:

```
parameters:
  - name: foodObject
    type: object
    default:
    - Food1: 'Apple'
    - Food2: 'Bread'
    - Food3: 'Cheese'
jobs:
  - job: test_loop
    displayName: 'Test Loop'
    pool: 
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
      - ${{ each food in parameters.foodObject }} :
        - powershell: |
            Write-Host "Food name is '${{ food.key }}' and value is '${{ food.value }}'"
```

However I get an error:

[image: error regarding template input]

**If the pipeline has an object parameter and I send that to the template, it works.**

It seems like by "building" the object myself from string parameters, it never actually becomes a "mapping" (???) even though there are key value pairs separated by ":".

I've tried different formatting using " or ' or multiple lines or spaces and whatnot, and can't get this to work.

The error doesn't seem to refer to the input parameter, but rather to the "each" loop that is on line 9.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when using your YAML sample.

The cause of the issue can be that the format of the object parameters has issue when you pass to the template.

To solve this issue, you can use the following sample:

Main YAML:

```
parameters:
  - name: Food1
    type: string
  - name: Food2
    type: string
  - name: Food3
    type: string

jobs:
  - template: .\testLoop.yml
    parameters: 
      foodObject: 
      - name: food1
        value: ${{ parameters.Food1 }}
      - name: food2
        value: ${{ parameters.Food2 }}
      - name: food3
        value: ${{ parameters.Food3 }}
```

Template YAML:

```
parameters:
  - name: foodObject
    type: object
    default:
    - name: food1
      value: apple
    - name: food2
      value: Bread
    - name: food3
      value: Cheese
jobs:
  - job: test_loop
    displayName: 'Test Loop'
    pool: 
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
      - ${{ each food in parameters.foodObject }} :
        - powershell: |
            Write-Host "Food name is '${{ food.name }}' and value is '${{ food.value }}'"
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

Here is another format of the YAML sample

Main:

```
parameters:
  - name: Food1
    type: string
  - name: Food2
    type: string
  - name: Food3
    type: string

jobs:
  - template: .\testLoop.yml
    parameters: 
      foodObject: 
        Food1: ${{ parameters.Food1 }}
        Food2: ${{ parameters.Food2 }}
        Food3: ${{ parameters.Food3 }}
```

Template:

```
parameters:
  - name: foodObject
    type: object
    default:
    - Food1: 'Apple'
    - Food2: 'Bread'
    - Food3: 'Cheese'
jobs:
  - job: test_loop
    displayName: 'Test Loop'
    pool: 
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
      - ${{ each food in parameters.foodObject }} :
        - powershell: |
            Write-Host "Food name is '${{ food.key }}' and value is '${{ food.value }}'"
```

Comment: Hi @kevin, thank you for responding. I'm aware this was option and was working, however what I wanted was to be able to "build" the object parameter based on data from difference sources, not just pass an object param unchanged between templates.

Comment: @Diogo When you pass parameters from the main YAML to the template YAML, you need to keep the format of the parameters consistent. Then sample in the answer can also supports to pass the different data to the YAML template with the `${{ parameters.Foodx }}` .It makes it easier to use parameter values in your template.

Comment: @Diogo I have shared another format of the YAML sample in the Updated answer. Please check if it can meet your requirement. I have retained the YAML parameter format from your original post to the greatest extent and made some adjustments

Comment: When you pass multiple lines of the object parameter, you don't need to add `|` before the value. It should be work when you remove the `|`. Change `foodObject: |` to `foodObject:`

Comment: Thank you @Kevin, removing the "|" header has solved it. Many thanks!